# Find previous workday if holiday

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there similar a formula in excel to `=WORKDAY()`, except on holidays it returns previous working day e.g. `=WORKDAY(A1; 5; DATE(2018; 8; 15))` and i need the formula to return 2018/08/14

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the interval if the holiday is going to change the result.

```
=WORKDAY(A1,  5-(WORKDAY(A1,  5,  DATE(2018, 8, 15))<>WORKDAY(A1,  5)),  DATE(2018, 8, 15))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula `WORKDAY` already does that. For example:

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(); -1; TODAY()-1)
```

Will give you the day before yesterday, not yesterday.
You just have to specify the holidays as the third argument.